# Issue with setting up StorageAccountname while starting Azure machine through Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to install and configure Azure Powershell and surprisingly I am facing issue with setting up of StorageAccountName parameter.

I have my vm setup on my enterprise account with resource group name as `"RG-1"` and storage account names as `rg13675 and rg16461`. I found these storage account names after drilling down to my resource group.

On running command,

`Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount –ResourceGroupName “RG-1” –StorageAccountName “rg16461"`

My powershell throws up error:

```
Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount : The Resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/rg16461' under resource group 'RG-1' was not found.

At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount –ResourceGroupName “RG-1” –StorageAc ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.SetAzureRmCurrentStorageAccount
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because your storage account is a `classic` storage account (from the screenshot you shared) while the cmdlet expects a `resource manager (ARM)` storage account.

Please create a new storage account using `Resource Manager` deployment option and try to use that account's name in your cmdlet. That should fix the error.

Comment: That makes sense, so https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/ doesn't seem to be the right link to follow does it? I need to Install a module for Azure classic?